# VBA for looking up values

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,
I need to look up a values in columns J & K of sheet 1 to see if either column in the row are <3.5.   If they are, I need to Copy that line to a sheet.  This would repeat for each line on a spreadsheet.  Then on Sheet 2 find the same starting mile marker in Column C and copy the next 10 lines below the condition found on sheet 1.

IE:

- sheet 1
  [image]
- sheet 2
  [image]
- Sheet 3
  [image]

In this case I would expect to see the following

- sheet 1 Row 2 column J is <3.5.  Certain cells from Row 2 would be copied to sheet 3 starting on column A
- sheet 2 Row 2 Column C matches Row 2 Column C from sheet 1.  Rows 3-11 would be copied on sheet 3 starting on Column M.  I have also shown another instance for R1......

Sheet 3 would list out all of the instances found without skipping lines

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the first requirement:

```
Sub test()

Dim row As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sheet2Row As Long


Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).row
sheet2Row = 1

For row = 2 To LastRow
    If sht.Cells(row, 10) > 3.5 Or sht.Cells(row, 10) > 3.5 Then
        sht.Range(row & ":" & row).Copy sht2.Range(sheet2Row & ":" & sheet2Row)
        sheet2Row = sheet2Row + 1
    End If

Next row


End Sub
```

I do not however understand the second part of your question "Then on Sheet 2 find the same starting mile marker in Column C and copy the next 10 lines below the condition found on sheet 1."

Comment: for the second part;  Sheet 1 is showing data in .1 of a mile.  Sheet 2 is showing the same  data in .01 of a mile.  So if sheet 1 shows 5.7 to 5.6 is showing a value <4.0 in either column J or K I then need to look at 5.69 through 5.60 on sheet 2 and list the lines that are < 3.5